# How can I delete all blocks in a particular selection of chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to delete all blocks in a particular selection of chunks.

1. The selection is pretty large, so loaded chunks mechanism prevents me from selecting the whole region, all I can select is ~ 900 chunks, while my aim is 100000 chunks.
2. Even if I do so 900 at a time, MCEDIT allows you to select chunks, and delete them, but then the minecraft terrain generator responds to its intrusion by regenerating the aformentioned chunks.
3. Also, doing it 900 at a time, will make me do so, until my hair turns grey XD.

So, is there a way to edit such a large selection, leave editing, is there even a way to make such a large selection?

Comment: i don't know of any mod or easy way to do this, however if it could be done, i would imagine it would be through editing the actual world save. i think you are looking for a good "NBT editor" i might be wrong about that though. not since 1.3 have i had to edit worldsaves.

Comment: Can I ask why you need to delete all blocks in a roughly 5000 x 5000 block area?

Comment: For a particular mission in an adventure map. (By particular I mean that the whole selection must not be empty, its a small area really)

Comment: OP: if your still interested, world edit for single player would definitely work.

Answer (score 2):

Try the /fill command. If you fill with minecraft:air, the selected region will disappear. Usage:

> /fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 minecraft:air

Troubleshooting: if it says "cannot place blocks outside of world", go into the middle of the selected region (do not go IN the selected region, just into the part of the chunk that needs to be loaded). If it says: "(whatever your block fill count is) > (maximum blocks)", start half at a time. If this grammar is incorrect, please edit it.

Comment: Seeing there would be 1750000000 blocks to remove, and the fill limit being 32768, this would take an ABSURD amount of time.